# push notification disappear on screen

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

My iPhone's screen is locked and sometimes, when I send push notifications a from PHP script, it disappears automatically. What can be the reason for this issue?

I use background fetch execution for `didReceiveRemoteNotification`:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)   (UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    NSLog(@"Notification received: %@", userInfo);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);

    // 100 lines of code

}
```

Comment: the reason could be expired time of push notification.

Comment: but it disappears suddenly when it comes to screen...

Comment: is it your own pushes or another app? try to remove did receive notification method. you don't have to implement it to just get pushes.

Comment: my own pushes...i need to execute some codes when received push...

Comment: try to comment your method then send push again. if this method don't expire your push.

Comment: Is it possible that your completionHandler code is setting the number of notifications to 0 ? That would make it disappear.

Comment: i only use set badge 0 in 
applicationWillEnterForeground
applicationDidEnterBackground
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

@Nick